# What's the best way to reboot a Mac that has crashed remotely (via SSH)? "shutdown -r now" or "sudo reboot" or?

Tags: macos, crash, ssh, shutdown, reboot

For example, I often end up with a situation were I'm logged in over Apple Remote Desktop (Teamviewer etc.) and the computer crashes...ARD says reconnecting, but doesn't...

However, I can nearly always still access the computer via SSH. But what often happens is, even after logging in and sending `shutdown -r now` or `sudo reboot`, it still doesn't reboot. It just ends up hanging...

Things not being saved etc. etc. isn't relevant, I just want to bring the computer back up...so the closest command to just physically power cycling it basically?

What about some of the options here:
https://ss64.com/osx/reboot.html

`sudo reboot -lnq` maybe?

or here:
https://ss64.com/osx/shutdown.html

`sudo shutdown -r now -k` maybe?

`Something else`?!?

Thanks for any help/thoughts!

P.S. I do have a failsafe, I can power cycle it with a smart plug...and that nearly always works...but I'd prefer not to have to rely on that so often. And then I have another failsafe for that, i.e. if "Start up automatically after a power failure" doesn't work (sometimes it doesn't), I have this set up to turn the computer on every hour: https://www.dssw.co.uk/powermanager ...just thought I'd add those for anyone who is interested...they'd saved me many a trip...